# How to use Rmpi in R on linux Cluster to increase cores available with DEoptim?

Tags: linux, r, parallel-processing

I am using code developed in R to calibrate a hydrological model with 8 parameters using DEoptim (a function that aims to minimise an objective function).  The DEoptim code uses the 'parallel' package to detect the number of cores available using 'DetectCores()'.  On my PC I have 4 cores with 2 threads each so it detects 8 cores and then sends out the hydrological model to a core with different values of parameters and the results are returned to the centre.  It does this hundreds or thousands of times and iterates the parameters to try and find an optimum set.  Therefore the more cores available, the faster it will work.

I am at a university and have access to a Linux compute cluster.  They have servers with up to 12 cores (i.e. not threads) and if I used this it would work two - three times faster than my PC.  Great.  However, ideally I would spread the code around other servers so I could have access to more cores and all the info sent back the master.

Therefore, my question is how could I include Rmpi in my code to effectively increase the cores available.  As you can probably tell, I am quite new to using clusters.

Many thanks, Antony

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute `DEoptim` on multiple nodes of a Linux cluster, I believe you'll need to use `foreach` by specifying `parallelType=2` in the `control` argument. You can use either the `doMPI` parallel backend or the `doParallel` backend with an MPI cluster object. For example:

```
library(doParallel)
library(Rmpi)
cl <- makeCluster(mpi.universe.size()-1, type='MPI')
registerDoParallel(cl)

# and eventually...
DEoptim(fn=Genrose, lower=rep(-25, n), upper=rep(25, n),
  control=list(NP=10*n, itermax=maxIt, parallelType=2))
```

You'll need to have the `snow` package installed in addition to the others. Also, make sure that you execute your script with mpirun using the `-np 1` option. If you don't use mpirun, the workers will all be spawned on the local machine.

Comment: Many thanks - how many machines will this employ i.e. is mpi.universe.size() the total number of machines in the cluster?  Looking forward to trying the code.

Comment: @user2901667 No. The value returned by mpi.universe.size() generally depends on the arguments to mpirun. For example, if you specify a machine/host file with 10 hosts listed, then mpi.universe.size() should return 10. If your MPI installation was built with support for your batch queueing system, then the value returned by mpi.universe.size() will depend on the number of cores that you requested when you submitted your job.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Will this (Rmpi) work with the parallel package (i..e parallelType=1).  I ask because I have the code working fine across multiple cores and not sure what arguments to supply to foreachArgs as part of DEoptim control.  When using parallel type = 1 I have to supply the variables and packages through parVar and packages in DEoptim control.

Comment: @user2901667 No. If you specify parallelType=1, a cluster object is created using `parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())`, and there doesn't appear to be a way to customize the way it is created in DEoptim version 2.2-3.